# How can I filter certain words in senders's address with gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-apps

I have been receiving a lot of spam from a shopping service I have an account with. The emails that they normally send are from "buyer-info13.g@mail.[removed].com" or "notice-buyer04.g@mail.[removed].com"

I can easily mark the senders address as spam or automatically remove it, but the two numbers at the end (13 or 04) constantly change.

I was looking at [search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) but for some reason they do not work when I try `from:("notice-buyer" OR "buyer-info")`:

[image: Gmail search operator problem]

Is there any way I can make this filter work correctly? If this does not work, does regex filters work? I can easily do this with Outlook, but then I would have to keep Outlook running all the time to filter the emails. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gmail search operators for multiple terms require brackets, not parens. Example: {from:amy from:david}.

In your case, I'd probably enter the full email address, including the domain.

Reference: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en